# Find what cell another cell is referencing

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I want to know what column a cell is referring to. Based on the cell it refers to, a different formula will apply.

example:

> ```
>     A       B       C       D       E       F       G
>            HIGH    LOW            Choice          Gaude
>    Terry   20      50             50              LOW
>    Tom     40      1212           1212            LOW
>    James   101010  121            101010          HIGH
>    Serra   5                      5               HIGH
>    Sam     50      50             50              LOW
> ```

cell E formula

```
=c2
=c3
=b4
=b5
=b6
```

cell G formula

```
=IF(F8=D8,"LOW","HIGH")
```

The problem is that Sam is meant to be High.

I hope my example helps you understand my predicament.

Answer (score 1):

Are you manually entering the formula in the Choice column E?  Maybe it's better to make the Gaude column drive the Choice column instead:

Cell E formula

```
= If(Exact(G2, "HIGH"), B2, C2)
```

And instead of changing the referenced column in E, just change G cells to LOW or HIGH as you require.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your quextion correctly, you want a formula that can analyse the formuala contained in another cell, and tell what column it refers to.

You will need a UDF for thism such as

```
Function WhatColumn(r1 As Range) As Variant
    WhatColumn = Range(r1.Formula).Column
End Function
```

This will return a column *number* (2 for column B)
You would use this like

```
=IF(E8=2,"HIGH","LOW")
```

so if cell `E8` contains `=B8` `WhatColumn` will return `2`